# How to remove like on likebutton widget by pressing another button

Tags: flutter

In my code, I try to remove the like on the likebutton widget by making `_isliked` `false`.

Here is the likebutton widget:

```
LikeButton( 
  countPostion: CountPostion.bottom,
  likeCountPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 0.0),

  onTap: (isLiked) async {

    togglelikeStatus();
    return !isLiked;
  },

  isLiked:  _isliked.value,//initial state
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
  likeCount: tlike ?? 0,

  likeBuilder: (isLiked) {
    
    return     isLiked ? const Icon(
      Icons.favorite,
      size: 20,
      color: Colors.red,
    ): const Icon(
      FeatherIcons.heart,
      size: 20,
      color: Colors.white,
    );
  },
);
```

The value of `_isliked` is inverted in  attempt to remove the like  on the likebutton widget in the removelike() method

```
IconButton(
  icon: const LineIcon.accessibleIcon(color: Colors.white, size: 20,), 
  onPressed: ()  {
    removelike();
  }
);
```

When I do this, the button which removes the like has to be pressed twice. On the first press, the color of the likebutton briefly changes then goes back.

How can I achieve removing the like from the likebutton effectively?

Comment: you might be looking for condition if state , eg. `if(_isliked) YourWidget()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `_isLiked.value=false` and then add `setState((){})` to rebuild the UI.

Comment: can it be done without setstate()?

Comment: If you are using any other state management, then yes. Otherwise, if the value of the variable is changed, how will you notify the widgets that the value is changed.

Comment: You can use state management packages like getx and Provider without using setstate.

Getx: https://pub.dev/packages/get

Provider: https://pub.dev/packages/provider